# Rails multiple model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a rails application with the following Models:

```
User (id)
Version (id, post_id, creator_id)
Post (id)
```

So far setup is as follows:

User.rb:

```
has_many :versions
```

Version.rb:

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :post
```

Post.rb:

```
has_many :versions
```

Now i would like to link a user to the posts he has through the versions table, and to make it worst this connection must be called questions. I was thinking something like this:

Added to User.rb:

```
has_many :questions, :class_name => "Post", :source => :post, :through => :versions
```

Problem is this doesn't work and probably shouldn't since it doesn't know what the user key's name is in the versions table.

Error message:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: versions.user_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "versions" ON "posts"."id" = "versions"."post_id" WHERE "versions"."user_id" = 1

**I'm at a loss, help!**

**Note:** The only relationship that doesn't work is the final one `users <==> posts` a.k.a `users.questions`

Comment: not clear - the line `has_many :questions, :class_name => "Post"` is that for User or Post?  If for post you can remove all the Post stuff.

Comment: I've clarified, it's in the User model...

Comment: Have you considered using `vestal_versions` (https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) for versioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setup should work for you:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :versions, :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
has_many :questions, :through => :versions
```

**version.rb**

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :question, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => 'post_id'
```

**post.rb**

```
has_many :versions
```

Now you can access the questions like so: `User.first.questions`

Comment: Strange, since I tested this in a brand-new rails 3.1 app. Are you sure you put "belongs to :question" (rather than :post) in your versions.rb?

Comment: Also note the foreign key definition on the versions association in user.rb

Comment: worked! I must of done something wrong the first time round, question is, Is there a way to define, explicitly, in a many to many through relation the names of the foreign keys on both sides?

Comment: No there is not because the association declaration is unidirectional. You declare it along the path from user to post (or vice versa).